# Python : List of Lists

Tags: python, list

I'm a beginer in python and for my project I have a List of lists.
And I try to show the lists I need  searching by one of their elements.

In my case it's a List that contain users informations(Name, username, age, country,...)

And I want to show, in this List, all the lists where the country is 'japan' for exemple. Not just the number of lists that does have it but show the integrality of the lists that contain this element.

But I don't know how to, so if someone know how to help me please say it.

Comment: Posting a sample input, and your expected output is multiple times more useful than trying to explain it in words.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code and data you're working with

Comment: Agree about better explaination/sample needed.  Especially explain relationship between name, username, age, ...
here is a link to info about list of lists : https://blog.finxter.com/python-list-of-lists/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of generating a list of list: list of lists of username, country, age that relate to each other

```
import pandas as pd
lst = [['u1','u2','u3','u4'],['c1','c2','c3','c2'],['a1','a2','a3','a4']]
cols = ['list_1','list_2','list_3','list_4']
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=cols).transpose()
df


         0   1   2
list_1  u1  c1  a1
list_2  u2  c2  a2
list_3  u3  c3  a3
list_4  u4  c2  a4
```

To find specific lists:

```
df[df[1] == 'c2']


         0   1   2
list_2  u2  c2  a2
list_4  u4  c2  a4
```